# Click event loose target after empty().append() element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have a function `addItems` that adds items dynamically to element `<div id="totalPremium"></div>` so it empty the `div` and adds items every time the function is called

```
function addItems(){
   /....../
   $("#totalPremium").empty();
   $("#totalPremium").append("<div>item</div>");
}
```

Below the click event function picks up a added item

```
$("#totalPremium > div").bind('click', function () {
    //do stuffs
}
```

And the problem is the very first time a item is added I can pick it up by the click function but after a new item is replaced the previous one, the click even seems looses its target and doesn't perform. I'm searching advice to make it work.

Comment: `$("#totalPremium").on('click','div', function () {
    //do stuffs
}`
Try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for dynamically added items

```
$("#totalPremium").on('click','div', function () {
    //do stuffs
});
```

Comment: +1, though that ends up being for *descendants* rather than children. I believe `'> div'` is valid in delegation selectors. It matters in terms of what `this` and `event.target` will be if the `div` has any descendants: http://jsbin.com/abubic/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/abubic/1/edit)).

Answer (score 0):

The click-handler will only be applied to elements that are present after calling it. If you remove the elements and add new ones, they don't have the clickhandler automatically. YOu have to add the handlers every time you create new elements